# Problemas ao recuperar dados do BD com Entity 6.1.3 e Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Fiz um projeto de testes, chamado cotacao para usar o Web API e o Entity. Bem, fui am meu web.config e criei a minha string de conexão assim:

```
<add name="CotacaoContext" connectionString="Data Source=Minha_Maquina\Instancia; Initial Catalog=Cotacao; User Id=sa; Password=d123" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Esse provider está aí, porque antes havia dado erro da falta dele, por isso eu o coloquei. Na minha controller fiz um método para pegar os usuários do BD e está dando pau. Esse é meu método no Controller(todo o código).

```
public class UsuarioController : ApiController
    {
        private CotacaoContext contexto = new CotacaoContext("CotacaoContext");

        [AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<Usuarios> GetUsuarios()
        {
            return contexto.Usuario.AsEnumerable();
        }

        public Usuarios GetUsuarioById(int id)
        {
            Usuarios usuario = contexto.Usuario.Find(id);
            if(usuario == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            return usuario;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            contexto.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Essa é a minha classe de Contexto que vai criar os DbSets e se conectar no banco.

```
public class CotacaoContext : DbContext
    {
        public CotacaoContext(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Usuarios> Usuario { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Login> Login { get; set; }
    }
```

E essa é a minha model que abstrai a tabela do banco de dados.

```
public class Usuarios
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Tipo_Usuario { get; set; }
        public string NMUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }
```

Uma observação importante. Existe 6 registro na tabela que eu coloquei na mão, e existe uma tabela que faz uma foreign key na tabela usuário, mas como eu estou testando a conexão primeiro, não coloquei no meu modelo ainda. Abaixo um print no momento do debug.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que quando coloco o mouse na variável contexto, aparecem 6 itens, mas com uma interrogação(minha tabela possui 6 registros). Estou desde ontem à noite na internet, para tentar descobrir o porque, mas falta um pouco mais de conhecimento(é o que eu estou buscando). No aguardo.

**Edit1** - Um ponto importante. O atributo `[AcceptVerbs("Get")]` coloquei depois, na tentativa de acertar.

**Edit2** - Veio uma luz. Eu preciso fazer alguma coisa no arquivo de rotas do web api?

**Edit3** - Quando executo, tanto no browser quanto no Postman, vem esse resultado: []

Comment: Você já tentou passa sua string de conexão direto no base(connectionString) do DbContext ? ou seja base("CotacaoContext")

Comment: Já havia feito assim: `..("name=CotacaoContext")`. Também esqueci de dizer, mas chamo meu serviço assim na URL: `http://localhost:6741/api/usuario`

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. Falatava um ToList() no return do método:

```
return contexto.Usuario.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```